# sql; percent distribution with counted values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distribution, percentage

I have a table (Salaries) with salaries distributed on gender and job titel.
I want to show the results on gender for every job titel I have in my database plus the total value. For example for the first titel I have this code:

```
select 'Female' as '____',
       count(gender) as Number,
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary,
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries
where gender= 'Female'
  And Job_titel='Adm assistent'
union (
select 'Man' as '____',
       count(gender) as Number,
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary,
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries
where gender= 'Man'
  AND Job_titel='Adm assistent')
union (
select 'Total' as '____',
       count(gender) as Number,
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary,
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries
where Job_titel ='Adm assistent' )
```

### The table:

```
  ____  Number Tot_Salaries Min_Salaries Avg_Salaries Max_Salaries
----------------------------------------------------------

Female    142      1 000 000          XXXXXX         XXXXXXX      XXXXXXX  
Male       18        300 000          XXXXXX         XXXXXXX      XXXXXXX
Total     160      1 300 000          XXXXXX         XXXXXXX      XXXXXXX
----------
```

Now I want the table to have the distribution in % for gender an salaries like this:

```
   ___  Number %_Gender Tot_Salaries %  Min_Salaries Avg_Salaries Max_Salaries

Female    142    89     1 000 000   77   XXXXXX      XXXXXXX     XXXXXXX  
Male       18    11       300 000   13   XXXXXX      XXXXXXX     XXXXXXX
Total     160   100     1 300 000   00   XXXXXX     XXXXXXX      XXXXXXX
----------
```

How do I get this two distrubution values? I Think my code maybe is quite ineffective right now:-)I use MS sql server.

Comment: Dump the data in a temp table and calculate the percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 declared variable for  totalcount and totalsalary

```
declare @totalgender  decimal(12,1)
declare @totalSalary  decimal(12,1)

select @totalgender=(select count(gender) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent' )
select @totalSalary=(select SUM(Salary) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent' )

select 'Female' as '____',
       count(Salaries.gender) as Number, cast(count(Salaries.gender) / @totalgender*100 as int),
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary, cast(SUM(Salary) / @totalSalary*100 as int),
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries   
where gender= 'Female'
  And Job_titel='Adm assistent'
union (
select 'Man' as '____',
       count(gender) as Number, cast(count(Salaries.gender) / @totalgender*100  as int),
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary, cast(SUM(Salary) / @totalSalary*100 as int),
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries
where gender= 'Man'
  AND Job_titel='Adm assistent')
union (
select 'Total' as '____',
       count(gender) as Number, cast(count(Salaries.gender) / @totalgender*100  as int),
       SUM(Salary) AS Total_Salary, cast(SUM(Salary) / @totalSalary*100 as int),
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries
where Job_titel ='Adm assistent' )
```

> or join table with select  `(select Job_titel, cast(count(gender )as decimal(5,2)) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent'  group by Job_titel) stot`

```
select 'Female' as '____',
       count(s.gender) as Number, max(stot.total),
          cast(count(s.gender)/max(stot.total)*100 as int),
       SUM(s.Salary) AS Total_Salary,  
       MIN(s.salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(s.salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(s.salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries s inner join 
    (select Job_titel, cast(count(gender )as decimal(5,2)) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent'  group by Job_titel) stot 
    on s.Job_titel= stot.Job_titel 
where gender= 'Female'
  And s.Job_titel='Adm assistent'
union  
select 'Man' as '____',
       count(s.gender) as Number, max(stot.total),
          cast(count(s.gender)/max(stot.total)*100 as int),
       SUM(s.Salary) AS Total_Salary,  
       MIN(s.salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(s.salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(s.salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries s inner join 
    (select Job_titel, cast(count(gender )as decimal(5,2)) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent'  group by Job_titel) stot 
    on s.Job_titel= stot.Job_titel 
where gender= 'Man'
  And s.Job_titel='Adm assistent'  
union  
select 'Total' as '____',
       count(s.gender) as Number, max(stot.total),
          cast(count(s.gender)/max(stot.total)*100 as int),
       SUM(s.Salary) AS Total_Salary,  
       MIN(s.salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(s.salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(s.salary) AS Max_Salary
from Salaries s inner join 
    (select Job_titel, cast(count(gender )as decimal(5,2)) as total from Salaries where Job_titel ='Adm assistent'  group by Job_titel) stot 
    on s.Job_titel= stot.Job_titel 
where S.Job_titel ='Adm assistent'
```

Comment: Thanks. This works almost  fine. But I doesnt got it real as I want because  the third column isn´t what i want and I miss the header for column 3 and I miss the percentage distribution female/male for Total Salaries, see this link what I got with your code;    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e72b9/1

Comment: For your first exemaple I give you real credit. it works to 99 %. except that there is no headers for percentage distribution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi again. I checked again and the genders percentage values doesn´t show 100 %. The total yes but the female gets 66 % and men 33 % , se this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7fde5/1  It has something to do with rounding of course but can you please show me how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

this would be much more optimized. No need to query from Salaries table multiple times.

```
SELECT Job_title,gender,
        count(gender) as Number,
       SUM(salary) AS Total_Salary,
       MIN(salary) AS Min_salary,
       AVG(salary) AS Avg_Salary,
       MAX(salary) AS Max_Salary
   INTO #t
FROM Salaries
WHERE Job_title ='Adm assistent'
GROUP BY Job_title, gender

SELECT t.Job_title, t.gender, t.Number, 
        CASE WHEN t2.tot_num = 0 THEN 0 ELSE  t.Number/CAST(t2.tot_num AS float) * 100 END as [pct_gender],
        t.Total_Salary, t.Min_salary, t.Avg_Salary, t.Max_Salary
FROM #t t
    INNER JOIN  (SELECT Job_title, SUM(Number) AS tot_num
                FROM #t
                GROUP BY Job_title) t2 
        ON t2.Job_title = t.Job_title 
UNION   
SELECT t.Job_title, 'Total', SUM( t.Number),    
        100 as [pct_gender],
        SUM(t.Total_Salary), SUM(t.Min_salary) , SUM(t.Avg_Salary), SUM( t.Max_Salary)
FROM #t t
GROUP BY t.Job_title
ORDER BY Job_title,Number

DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: Thanks.! The total values for gender is ok. But for the Min,AVG,MAX salaries It not right.  For the AVG_Salaries Totalvalue It shall count on the whole population, here it just sum up female an mens average salaries. The same for Min and Max totalvalues;it shall count on the whole population in this way; Female_Min=10 000, Male_Min=25000, then the total shall be 10 000. Then I miss the percent distribution for the Total Salaris for female and men in the same manner as the prc_gender. Thanks for your help I´m on my way here :-) I appreciates if you could help me with this.