# SQL syntax to SUM a Count column for calculating percentage distribution

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following query which runs fine:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT [Room Nights],
       COUNT([Room Nights]) AS 'Count of RN'
FROM HOLDINGS2
GROUP BY [Room Nights]
```

The output is as follows:

```
Room Nights      Count of RN
 1                 3
 4                 10
 5                 6
 7                 25
```

Now I want to show another column that gives me the percentage distribution of the `Count of RN`. Hence, my output will need to be like this:

```
Room Nights      Count of RN    % Distribution
     1                 3           6.8
     4                 10          22.7
     5                 6           13.6
     7                 25          56.8
```

I had a look at the following discussion to try to find out a solution:
[percent distribution with counted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170489/sql-percent-distribution-with-counted-values).

I came up with the following amendments to my existing code but it's not working! I am having only zeroes in the `% Distribution` column.

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT [Room Nights],
       COUNT([Room Nights]) AS 'Count of RN',
       CAST(COUNT([Room Nights])/(SELECT COUNT([Room Nights])*100. FROM HOLDINGS2) AS DECIMAL (9,0)) AS '% Distribution'
FROM HOLDINGS2
GROUP BY [Room Nights]
```

Basically, the `% Distribution` column should take the `Count of RN` and divide it by the TOTAL `Count of RN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
select [Room Nights],
  count([Room Nights]) AS 'Count of RN',
  cast(
    (count([Room Nights])
    /
    (Select Count([Room Nights]) * 1.0 from HOLDINGS2) 
   ) * 100 as decimal(6,1)
  ) as '% Distribution'    
FROM HOLDINGS2
GROUP BY [Room Nights]
```

The `* 1.0` in the subquery forces a floating point division, and the outer cast limits the precision.

Or, as you're using a modern version of MSSQL you could use window functions:

```
cast(count([Room Nights])/(sum(count([Room Nights])*1.0) over ()) * 100 as decimal(6,1))
```

Comment: This, or adding an inner cast to either the numerator or the denominator. I modified ughai's original answer to *first* convert the count to decimal *then* divide it by the total, which works - but gives you large precision so you'd need to round or have an outer cast.

Comment: @jpw, just a minor defect. You are missing group by clause

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks for noticing, forgot to copy that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function to calculate `% Distribution`, multiply by `100.0` to force the result to be `float` and then leave everything up to 1 digit after the comma:

```
select [Room Nights]
      , count([Room Nights]) as [Count of RN]
      , cast(100.0 * count([Room Nights])/(sum(count([Room Nights])) over ()) as decimal(6,1)) as [% Distribution]
from HOLDINGS2
group by [Room Nights]
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79abc/14)

You can also use a subquery :

```
select [Room Nights]
     , count([Room Nights]) as [Count of RN]
     , cast(100.0 * count([Room Nights])/(select count([Room Nights]) from HOLDINGS2) as decimal(6,1)) as [% Distribution]
from HOLDINGS2
group by [Room Nights]
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/79abc/15)

Comment: you would need to convert the distribution to decimal or numeric to get distribution % with precision points.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      [Room Nights] INT ,
      [Count of RN] INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 4, 10 ),
        ( 5, 6 ),
        ( 7, 25 )


SELECT  * ,
        ROUND([Count of RN] * 100.0
              / SUM([Count of RN]) OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ), 1) AS [Percent]
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
Room Nights Count of RN Percent
1           3           6.800000000000
4           10          22.700000000000
5           6           13.600000000000
7           25          56.800000000000
```

EDIT: I've missed that Count of RN is result of grouping query. Here is modified statement:

```
SELECT  [RN] ,
        COUNT(S) AS C ,
        CAST(COUNT(S) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(S)) OVER () AS DECIMAL(10, 1)) AS [Percent]
FROM    @t
GROUP BY [RN]
```

Comment: [Count of RN] is the result of a query and not part of the source. You could of course run the first query as a cte or a derived table though.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
select [Room Nights],
       count([Room Nights]) AS 'Count of RN',
       (CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),count([Room Nights]))/(Select Count([Room Nights]) from HOLDINGS2))*100 as '% Distribution'
FROM HOLDINGS2
GROUP BY [Room Nights]
```

Comment: I think you have a parenthesis missing at the end. Anyway, it still gives me zeroes everywhere in that column.

Comment: i missed it at the start. try now.